# how to hide the uiview user does not use the view?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4

I have one view like shortcuts view with some buttons.  Now when I click the shortcut button the shortcut view is appear now i want user does not touch the view how can hide the shortcuts view after 8 sec and also user touch the view  before 8 sec it will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UIView animations and move the view out of your screen

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.333f 
                      delay:8.0f 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut 
                 animations:^(void) {
                      myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,self.view.frame.size.height);
                           }
                 completion:nil];
```

In this example I am moving your view to the bottom of the screen, `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x,y)` moves the frame of your view by the given x and y points

And to move it back, well, you get the drift ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay`  and `+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget` methods

```
-(void)showShortcuts
{
    // all the code you need to show your shortcuts view
    ...
    [self perfornSelector:@selector(hideShortcuts) withObject:nil afterDelay:8.0];
}

-(void)hideShortcuts
{
// all the code you need to hide your shortcuts view
...
}

-(void)shortcutPressed:(id) shortcut
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    // code your shortcut is supposed to trigger
    ...
}
```